# Connect ODBC throught another VM?

Tags: web-server, ubuntu-18.04, unixodbc

I have a big issue in my company. I am trying to migrate a web application from Windows to Linux; everything works fine, except the ODBC connection.

We have 3 databases, each one of them provide a driver. But I need two different driver managers (iODBC and UnixOdbc)

**UnixOdbc**:

- SqlServer
- Advantage Database (SAP solution)

**iODBC**:

- HyperfileSql

Actually it's impossible to have both driver managed in the same machine.

Is it possible to install iODBC with Hyperfile driver in another VM and make possible for my web apps to connect in ODBC through the VM?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot access a database driver that is installed on a remote machine like a locally installed one.

But you should be able to install all your (x)ODBC drivers on one system and access them through different DSNs.

Comment: > No, you cannot access a database driver that is installed on a remote machine like a locally installed one. >But you should be able to install all your (x)ODBC drivers on one system and access them through different DSNs. Yep, but if i install iodbc and unixodbc in together in ubuntu, my PHP app are unable to recognize driver from unixOdbc (it's seems iodbc are linked with php?), What should i do?

Comment: I don't know about iodbc. But it seems the root of your problem lies within this one; triple check those modules, test the connection and debug there. xODBC is built for allowing multiple database interface drivers - it would be *very* strange if this drivers wiuldn't allow this exact thing.